# Force hg update to treat numeric value as branch name not text

Tags: mercurial

I made the mistake of creating a numeric feature branch name:

```
hg branch 123
```

Now, when I try to update to 123, it is treated as a revision number by hg:

```
hg up 123
```

Instead of updating to the branch named 123, my source is updated to revision 123.  Is there any way to force the hg up command to consider 123 as a branch instead of rev. number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with: `hg update -r 'branch(123)'`

Comment: typo apostrophe before branch syntax?  it works if I remove the apostrophe but SO won't let me edit it to remove less than 6 characters -- maybe the OP can?  at any rate -- accepted

Comment: @LazyBadger - I am able to run `-r branch(123)` or `-r "branch(123)"` or `-r branch("123")` ... I just can't leave that apostrophe before the OP's word branch.

Comment: You're all right, I thought branchnames could be quotes in the revset, but I guess not.  On the outside single or double quotes work.